# How to pass parameters to a URL from a select form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I want to pass values from a **select form** to a URL in order to connect to an external website using iframe solutions.

I'm very to new to .PHP & JavaScript. Please help me out.

This is the form I created to get data from users to pass into a specific URL.

```
<form action="selectcourier.php" method="GET">
<h1>Select courier service</h1>

<select>
 <option value="Select">Select Courier Service</option>
 <option value="1">DTDC</option>
 <option value="2">AFL</option>
 <option value="3">BlueDart</option>
</select>

Consignment Number: <input type="text" name="cNum"><br>

<center><input type="submit"></center>
</form>
```

selectcourier.php

```
<body>
<form><center><h3><a href="http://dtdc.com/tracking/tracking_results.asp?action=track&sec=tr&ctlActiveVal=1&Ttype=awb_no&strCnno=H60874238&GES=N&TrkType2=awb_no&strCnno2=<?php echo $_GET["cNum"]; ?>" target="ifrm"> CONFIRM </a><h3></center>
```

```
<iframe id="ifrm" width=300 height=300 seamless src="http://example.com/">
</body>
```

My question:

Hope you have understood that I'm trying to give **all courier tracking service** right from my website using an iframe. But here I'm unable to differentiate the appropriate URLs for different types of Courier Service to pass the value (cNum) and open that web link in an iframe.

I have all the URLs of all courier services.

Now how can I differentiate them to pick up the appropriate URL when a Courier Service is selected by the User?

Kindly help me, please. Thanks.

Comment: So basicly you want a user to be able to select one of the courier tracking services and then that website should load inside an iframe?

Comment: have some database code in the iframe that processes the option selected from the `select` menu

Comment: @icecub: Thanks for your reply. Yes, u r right.

Comment: @RamRaider: Can you please give me an idea how to do that?

Comment: @RamRaider Nah, he simply wants a 3rd party website to load inside an iframe based on the selection menu. It's a simple matter of capturing the post or onchange event and send the correct url towards the iframe.

Comment: @icecub:  u r right. but how can I differentiate all the URLs of all courier services and get the appropriate URL for each one?

Comment: I'm working on an answer for you that shows how to do it. Please be a bit patient :)

Comment: @icecub:  k thanks my friend

Comment: yeah - noted that after your comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you simply want to load a url to an iframe based on the selection, I would go with this. Basic explanation can be found in the comments:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Set global variables
        var serviceSelect;
        var ConNumberElement;

        // Wait for the page to be loaded
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            // Get required elements
            serviceSelect = document.getElementById("CourierService");
            ConNumberElement = document.getElementById("cNum");
        });

        function loadWebsite(){
            // Get the iframe
            var ifrm = document.getElementById("ifrm");

            // Get Consignment Number
            var ConNumber = ConNumberElement.value;

            // Get Courier Service
            var serviceValue = serviceSelect.value;

            // Make sure a correct service is selected
            if(serviceValue == "1"){ // DTDC is selected
                ifrm.src = "http://dtdc.com/tracking/tracking_results.asp?action=track&sec=tr&ctlActiveVal=1&Ttype=awb_no&strCnno=" + ConNumber + "&GES=N&TrkType2=awb_no&strCnno2=" + ConNumber;
            } else if(serviceValue == "2"){ // AFL is selected
                ifrm.src = ""; // Add the correct url here. Take the example above on how to do it.
            } else if(serviceValue == "3"){ // BlueDart is selected
                ifrm.src = ""; // Add the correct url here. Take the example above on how to do it.
            } else {
                alert("You have to select a correct Courier Service");
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Select courier service</h1>

        <select id="CourierService">
            <option value="Select">Select Courier Service</option>
            <option value="1">DTDC</option>
            <option value="2">AFL</option>
            <option value="3">BlueDart</option>
        </select>

        Consignment Number: <input type="text" id="cNum"><br>

        <input type="button" onclick="loadWebsite();" value="CONFIRM" />

        <iframe id="ifrm" width=300 height=300 seamless src="http://example.com/">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: web page is not loading in the iframe when a courier service is selected and clicked on submit. how can i make it work?

Comment: @vIJAy Check your console. It is possible that the website you're trying to load inside the iframe doesn't allow cross-origin framing. I did test the code myself and it works fine so that's the only explanation I can think of.

Comment: @vIJAy Which browser are you using?

Comment: I also want to add
Consignment Number: <input type="text" name="cNum">

to pass this value in the URL to form the required final URL to get the status report of the consignment from that website in our iframe.

Comment: I'm using Chrome browser

Comment: I copied and pasted the complete code you've edited for me in my index page to check how it works.
plz find the same at  www.saveononline.com

Comment: @vIJAy I've updated the code. Please upload that towards your website.

Comment: Updated. Now I can find text field to enter consignment number. But still the page is not loading the generated URL and the showing up www.example.com only.

Plz chck the same on  www.saveononline.com

Comment: @vIJAy Updated the code again. It might still not work, but please update that website with it.

Comment: @vIJAy Seems to be working fine now on your website :)

Comment: @vIJAy I checked your website. It's working as expected. The iframe loads the website based on the value inside the input field. I can't fix what isn't broken

Comment: Yes :) It's working now. Thanks. You know the text field you've created for consignment number is a part of the URL for which we need to get from the user and pass into it. How can we achieve that my friend?

Comment: @vIJAy It's already doing that. Check line 28 of the code. At the end of the url the value of that input field is added to the url :)

Comment: @vIJAy Oh wait.. now I see your issue. In that case I have to update the entire code. Give me a few mins.

Comment: @vIJAy Ok I've updated the code again. Make sure you edit line 26 and line 28 with the correct URLs. Take a close look at line 24 on how to do it.

Comment: http://dtdc.com/tracking/tracking_results.asp?action=track&sec=tr&ctlActiveVal=1&Ttype=awb_no&strCnno=*value*&GES=N&TrkType2=awb_no&strCnno2=*value*

This is the URL for the first Courier Service: DTDC.
I marked 2 locations in this URL with name: *value* where we will need to pass the Consignment Number (cNum) to form the required URL to open in the iframe.

Please update this URL for the remaining Courier Services also, so that I can easily continue with your method of adding as many courier services for further. Thanks.

Comment: @vIJAy I've updated the code again. It is fully working for DTDC. Take a look at the comments inside the code on how to do it for the other services.

Comment: You are awesome Bjorn. It's working great. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Can you please guide me how to place the variable "ConNumber" in the URL?

Can I simply use "ConNumber" wherever it is required in the URL?
or need add any symbol like "+" like you've added in the URL?

Comment: @vIJAy No problem :) If an answer has helped you, please mark it as Answered. It's a way of showing your appreciation to the one that helped you out and it also prevents your question from remaining unanswered forever

Comment: @vIJAy That's very easy. `ConNumber` is the *Consignment Number*. So if you write an url it would be like: `ifrm.src = "http://www.url.com?number=" + ConNumber + "&someValue=1";`

Comment: k Thank you, Bjorn. You really helped me great. I'll remember you always throughout my website development and also further.
Can I also write to you directly if really required?

Comment: @vIJAy No you can't simply use it. `ConNumber` is a variable. So you should **NEVER** place it inside quotes: (" "). If you do, it would add the word ConNumber to url instead of the *Consignment Number*. That's why you need the + sign. Because you are *adding* the value of the variable to the url :)

Comment: @vIJAy Well it is as my profile says: If you need more indept help, you're allowed to email me. However, *ALWAYS* try to get your answer here on Stack Overflow first! Simply because I would be spammed like crazy if I started to help everyone out privately for free, haha